# A right triangle with the wrong perimeter

Tags: real-analysis

Here is a sequence of sets:

1. \begin{align}S_1 = \{(x, y) : 0 \le x \le 1, 0 \le y \le 1\}\end{align} is the unit square with lower-left corner at $(0, 0)$,
2. \begin{align}S_2 &= \{(x, y) : 0 \le x \le 1/2, 0 \le y \le 1\} \\
   &\cup \{(x, y) : 0 \le x \le 1, 0 \le y \le 1/2\}\end{align} is $S_1$ with the upper-right quadrant removed,
3. \begin{align}S_3 &= \{(x, y) : 0 \le x \le 1/4, 0 \le y \le 1\} \\
   &\cup \{(x, y) : 0 \le x \le 1/2, 0 \le y \le 3/4\} \\
   &\cup \{(x, y) : 0 \le x \le 3/4, 0 \le y \le 1/2\} \\
   &\cup \{(x, y) : 0 \le x \le 1, 0 \le y \le 1/4\}\end{align} is $S_2$ with the upper-right quadrant removed from its upper-left and lower-right quadrants,
4. etc.

We have:

$$\forall 0 \le x \le 1, \forall 0 \le y \le 1: \\
(x + y \le 1 \implies \forall i = 1, 2, 3, \ldots ((x, y) \in S_i))$$

We also have:

$$\forall 0 \le x \le 1, \forall 0 \le y \le 1: \\
(x + y > 1 \implies \exists i \in \{1, 2, 3, \ldots\} ((x, y) \notin S_i))$$

(It's sufficient to take $i \ge 1 - \log_2{(x+y-1)}$.)

This suggests that $\lim_{i \to \infty} S_i$ exists, and is equal to $T$, where $T = \{(x, y) : 0 \le x \le 1, 0 \le y \le 1, x + y \le 1\}$ is the right triangle with unit sides.

If we look at the sequence $A_i$ of the areas of $S_i$:

1. $A_1 = 1$
2. $A_2 = 3/4$
3. $A_3 = 5/8$
4. etc.

This suggests that $\lim_{i \to \infty} A_i$ exists, and is equal to $1/2$, which is $A(T)$.

But if we look at the sequence $P_i$ of the perimeters of $S_i$:

1. $P_1 = 4$
2. $P_2 = 4$
3. $P_3 = 4$
4. etc.

This suggests that $\lim_{i \to \infty} P_i$ exists, and is equal to 4.

But the perimeter of $T$ is $2 + \sqrt{2}$.

So, why is $P(\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n) \ne \lim_{n \to \infty} P(S_n)$?

I know that, in general, $f(\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n)$ need not equal $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)$.

My question is more, what is the qualitative difference here between area and perimeter that makes it so that area converges but perimeter doesn't?

Comment: See https://seriousmathsandunicorns.wordpress.com/2016/04/20/why-is-pi-not-equal-to-4/ for $\pi=4$.